# How do I update a record in a vector, matching certain criteria?

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to update records in a vector, which match certain criteria.

```
(defrecord Item [id name description])

(def items
  (ref [
    (->Item "1" "Cookies" "Good tasting!")
    (->Item "2" "Blueberries" "Healthy!")

  ])
)
```

How can I do e.g. "set name of item to "foo" where id is equal 1"?

I maybe need something like

```
(dosync (commute items ???? ))
```

Can't figure the ????

I found e.g. function [update-in in docs](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/update-in)

But 1. Can't find examples with records, 2. Not sure if I can use it to update a different field than the one I'm using to do the query. In the examples fields seem to be the same.

The complete use case: I have a webservice which update operation, where I get a map with the id of the item and optional fields which have to be updated.

I'm new to Clojure. I implemented remove function, by id, it works:

```
(commute items #(remove (fn [x](= (:id x) id)) %))
```

Also find by id, which might be a step in direction to update:

```
(nth (filtered (filter #(= (:id %) id) @items)) 0)
```

But don't know how to update the record in my vector...

Comment: I suggest you avoid state, make copies instead of modifying.  Most functions like `assoc` and company will return a new data structure (map in case of `assoc`) instead of the old one modified. Clojure was made to think about immutability instead of state change. When you get it this way (the *idiomatic* way) you will see how your code becomes more clear and succint. I made this mistake of using mutable myself, so this is my advice on it.

Comment: I'm aware of that. Actually, this data should be in a database. I'm just using in memory data temporarily.

Comment: Still doesn't matter, it's data. Anyway you might want to look into [ClojureQL](https://github.com/LauJensen/clojureql).

Comment: Ahh. You mean return a new, modified data structure instead of changing the element. Yes... it makes sense. I'm aware of the benefits of functional practices :) Right now just playing a bit to become fluent with the language... but will keep that in mind, of course.

Comment: @m0skit0 anyway, isn't this the way these functions work? remove returns a new, updated seq. The ref then has to be updated using dosync and commute. Also in the selected answer, mapv returns the updated seq, then ref is updated. Am I missing something?

Comment: Correct, if this is how you want to do it, then that's what I was saying. I just got confused my your wording about *update* a record. *Updating* for me means implicit mutable state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `assoc` to make a copy of a record with some keys replaced.

```
(dosync
 (commute items
          #(mapv (fn [i]
                   (if (= (:id i) "1")
                     (assoc i :name "foo")
                     i))
                 %)))
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I just had to change `(assoc i :name "foo")` with `(merge i params)` to update the item using my params map.